# Add Noise to a Dataset

Tags: white-noise, cholesky-decomposition

I've generated a dataset of 100 elements from a 3-variate Gaussian distribution with parameters $\mu = 0$ and $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho_1 & \rho_2 \\ \rho_1 & 1 & \rho_1 \\ \rho_2 & \rho1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. To generate such dataset, Cholesky factorization as been used on the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.
I followed [this](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/multivariate_normal_draws.html) for Python language.

The problem is related to adding noise to such dataset. I need to add noise $\eta_i \sim \mathbb{N}(0,1)$ to each $X_i \quad \forall i=1, \dots, 100$ in such a way its covariance matrix results to be $\Sigma* = \begin{pmatrix}1+noise & \rho_1 & \rho_2 \\ \rho_1 & 1+noise & \rho_1 \\ \rho_2 & \rho1 & 1+noise\end{pmatrix}$ that is noise does not alter (or it if does, for a very less amount) all the elements off-diagonal. Is it possible to do it? Or is the sample too small?

I just add the noise in such a way that $X_i + \eta_i$, should I multiply $\eta_i$ for $\mathbb{I}$ first?

Also $\eta$'s size is [100x3]: should it be smaller to have such $\Sigma*$?

## Update

My goal is to find such $X^*$, the dataset + noise, such that I can apply to it the whitening and colouring phases [(here)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329991807_Hiding_Alice_in_Wonderland_A_Case_for_the_Use_of_Signal_Processing_Techniques_in_Differential_Privacy_6th_Annual_Privacy_Forum_APF_2018_Barcelona_Spain_June_13-14_2018_Revised_Selected_Papers) and show that the only noise addition cannot preserve privacy of  users in the dataset, but a recolouring (whitening + colouring) are mandatory.

Thus, Noise addition is in Chaper 4 of [link](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1309/1309.3958.pdf) says that

> epsilon  is  the  random variable   (noise)   added   to X,   whose   distribution   is $(0,\sigma^2)$. Note  that  additive  noise  also known  as uncorrelated  noise, preserves  the  mean  and covariance   of   the   original   data   but   the   correlation coefficients  and  variances  are  not  sustained. Another variation  of  additive  noise  is correlated  additive  noisethat   keeps   the   mean   and   allows   the   sustenance of correlation coefficients in the original data.

Comment: You can adjust the variances on the diagonal without affecting the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix, but you will change the correlations. Perhaps you do indeed care about the covariance matrix and not at all about the correlation matrix, but my suspicion is that you want to keep the correlations as $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, which you will not do if you change the variances.

Comment: Indeed I need to maintain those correlations between data.
So is it actually possibile to add noise to a dataset in such a way to produce $\Sigma*$? @Dave

Comment: No, because the correlation coefficients determined by $\Sigma^{*}$ will not equal the $\rho_i$ unless "noise" is zero.

Comment: @whuber so what would be the best way to add noise to such dataset to minimize the differences between $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma*$?

Comment: That's an indeterminate question: it requires that you explain the purpose of adding noise.  Without such context, one answer is "make the noise zero."

Comment: @whuber Recolouring process [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329991807_Hiding_Alice_in_Wonderland_A_Case_for_the_Use_of_Signal_Processing_Techniques_in_Differential_Privacy_6th_Annual_Privacy_Forum_APF_2018_Barcelona_Spain_June_13-14_2018_Revised_Selected_Papers]

Comment: That's a helpful hint.  Could you edit your post to provide more details of what you hope these covariance matrices represent and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @whuber I've just done it.